# Avoid line breaks / paragraph gaps in posts when using custom HTML tags

Tags: html, css

Disclaimer: I'm super new to this and know very little about the technical terms. I might just not know what to search for in order to find the answer I need. In that case I would really appreciate someone just pointing me the right way.

Now, the problem/question:

Is there a way to avoid things like this:

```
<table>
<th>
<tr>One </tr>
<tr>Two</tr>
<tr>Three</tr>
</th>
</table>
```

displaying as if you typed this

```
<table><br>
<th><br>
<tr>One </tr><br>
<tr>Two</tr><br>
<tr>Three</tr><br>
</th><br>
</table><br>
```

because using "enter" in the text-box when writing a post is automatically rendered as a line break. Is there something you can put at the beginning of a post to overwrite/ignore this kind of global "enter = line break" thing for that post? As is, I have to type in tables and other things in this format to make it display correctly:

```
<table><th><tr>One </tr><tr>Two </tr><tr>Three </tr></th></table>
```

It gets a little hard to navigate after a while

(I can only use things that can be written directly into a post)

I'd really appreciate any kind of help - even if it is a plain and simple "nope, can't be done" - then I at least know I can stop searching ^^

Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating this problem. You can use the built in stack snippet in [edit] mode

Answer (score 0):

Newlines in HTML code should not matter (more precisely, they are just whitespaces) and they definitely do not render as newlines "by themselves".

If the newlines in yout HTML render as newlines on your screen, there must be something else in your HTML or CSS code that causes this. For example the [`<pre>` or `<code>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) HTML element or [`white-space:pre`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) in your CSS. All of these (and a few other ones) instruct the browser that newlines in HTML should render as newlines on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

It then looks like the site admin put it in the CSS (which I have no access to) and there is no way to circumvent it, without changing something in the CSS, if I understand you correctly (?)

Comment: What exactly do you HAVE access to? If you can edit the HTML, you can definitely also change the CSS to whatever you want. Can you share the URL to the actual page?

Comment: *"Newlines in HTML code should not matter"* - it matters for inline elements, not as dramatically as described in the question though.